# Force mysqldump to add row_format values to CREATE TABLE statements

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a case where I would like to generate a database dump where the `CREATE TABLE` statements include the `row_format` value.

I can't figure out how to do this - please can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Instead, create a short query that interrogates for that information in `information_schema` and creates `ALTER TABLE` statements for non-default row_formats.  The script could be a Stored Procedure the "prepares" and "executes" them.